How does Blenders Black and White work when saving?
I am trying to convert my color pictures to black and white when saving. My issue is that if I just convert the picture to black and white in Photoshop, the values are as expected in the mid grey range.
When blender does it in the Save As -> Black and White it super dark, almost black.
I have tried several experiments and I just dont understand the logic behind why it becomes so dark.
The blue color when rendering.

This is after converting to black and white in Save as.

This is my reference for converting in Photoshop.


I'm not getting the dark result, with the same shade of blue I'm getting something similar to the reference from Photoshop. Consider sharing your file with https://blend-exchange.com/

Thank you for your reply and sorry for the late answer! It really is just a simple cube that I am rendering. Now I tried with the compositor node "RGB to BW" which gives the correct result, but when I do Save As -> Black and white "Jpeg" it gives me the dark.
https://imgur.com/a/gAJioPk <- comparison of methods.

This doesnt match your first picture (2nd is brighter than first), which means you are doing something wrong, probably. Not enough information to help.
